# Matching infinite matrices

Tags: matrices

Can any one solve this problem that I have. I have been sitting with this problem for a while now. Completely confused.

"For inifinite matrices a complete matching may not be possible even though Hall's condition is satisfied. If the first row is all 1's and every a(i,i-1) = 1 , show that any p rows can have 1's in at least p columns and still there is no complete match"

Any help would be greatly appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Would help viewers if you defined what you mean by a complete matching.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix looks like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&\ldots\\
1&0&0&0&0&\ldots\\
0&1&0&0&0&\ldots\\
0&0&1&0&0&\ldots\\
0&0&0&1&0&\ldots\\
0&0&0&0&1&\ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you pick any $p$ rows not including the first row, they have $1$’s in exactly $p$ columns, and if your $p$ rows do include the first row, they have $1$’s in every column. Thus, the only real problem is to show that there is no complete match.

HINT: Suppose that you match the first row with column $k$; with which column are you going to match row $k+1$?